# using bootstrap modal, how can I get the value of a textbox and pass it on a PHP variable

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem on how to get the value of a textbox, i'm using modal bootstrap. I listed my data using while loop on PHP.

this is the code for displaying my data:

```
    $query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_messages where alumni= '$alumni' GROUP BY title  ");
        while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

         echo "<a href='messageview.php?id=$msgID#myModal' role='button'  data-toggle='modal'  data-title= '".$res['title']."' class='messages'>".$res['title']."</a>";
         echo "From:".$res['company'];
         echo $res['message'];
```

this is the modal.

> x
>               Message

```
            $db=mysql_query("select * from tbl_messages where title = '$msgTitle' and alumni = '$alumni' ")or die(mysql_error());
            while($sa=mysql_fetch_array($db)){

                echo "<div style='border:0px solid black;'>";
                echo "<b>".$sa['user'].":</b><br>";
                echo $sa['message'];
                echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
    </form>
```

The problem is, I want to get the $res['title'] that is listed on my while loop and pass is to the php variable to put on my SQL statement. Anyone can help me? please. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do the simple string concatenation?

```
$db=mysql_query("select * from tbl_messages where title = '" . $res['title'] . "'");
```

I haven't ran this code so you might want to play around with quote characters. Btw, I don't think the question has anything to do with Bootstrap.